# Add a new tokenizer method in apache solr

Tags: apache, solr, tokenize, stringtokenizer

Following title, I want to add a new tokenizer method into Apache Solr

```
http://mim.hus.vnu.edu.vn/phuonglh/softwares/vnTokenizer
```

My problem is I can't found any document about it. Is it possible ?

Comment: can you explain a little more what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @root545 I'm trying to use my Tokenizer method from 3th side( Specially design for my language ) in ApacheSolr. But I don't know how to to it. I have read Solr Tokenizers docs here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers
but I can't find out how to import my library into ApacheSolr.

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach you can use is described here: [Solr Plugins](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins): section about Tokenizers / TokenFilters.

In a few words you need to extend Solr's `org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer` and implement your logic there. Afterwards you need to declare your new field type with your own tokenizer / token-filter.